# How to Get the imageurl of partular tag element in silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I am binding the items as follows:

```
    <ScrollViewer>
       <ItemsControl x:Name="UserList">
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
             <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding imageurl}" 
                       Tag="{Binding Path=id}" Width="164" Height="150" 
                       Margin="4" Stretch="Fill"></Image>

             </DataTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>

Code.cs:


    List.Add(new StackImages { id = "1", Name="test",type="test",price ="testprice" ,imageurl = new Uri(this.BaseUri, @"Assets/acservice.png") });
    List.Add(new StackImages { id = "2", imageurl = new Uri(this.BaseUri, @"Assets/brakes.png") });
    List.Add(new StackImages { id = "3", imageurl = new Uri(this.BaseUri, @"Assets/carwash.png") });
    List.Add(new StackImages { id = "4", imageurl = new Uri(this.BaseUri, @"Assets/oilchange.png") });
    List.Add(new StackImages { id = "5", imageurl = new Uri(this.BaseUri, @"Assets/transmission.png") });
    UserList.ItemsSource= List;
```

Please tell me how to get particulat imageurl of the particular  tag value when tap on it?

Comment: i am adding name,type,price values also to list .How to get that?I am not binding those elements in UI.check my edit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [answer given to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17969212/1136211) you have two options. Either you access the `Source` property of the Image control and cast it to `BitmapImage` (that's what WPF creates by automatic type conversion from `Uri` to `ImageSource`):

```
private void MyTapHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image image = (Image)sender;
    BitmapImage bitmap = (BitmapImage)image.Source;
    Uri uri = bitmap.UriSource;
}
```

Or you access the `StackImage` object in the Image's `DataContext`:

```
private void MyTapHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image image = (Image)sender;
    StackImage stackImage = (StackImage)image.DataContext;
    Uri uri = stackImage.imageurl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is to *select* an item from a list. In order to support selection, you have to replace the `ItemsControl` by a `ListBox`.

```
<ListBox x:Name="UserList" SelectionMode="Single"
         SelectionChanged="UserList_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding imageurl}" 
                   Tag="{Binding Path=id}" Width="164" Height="150" 
                   Margin="4" Stretch="Fill"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now you may attach a handler to the [`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event and you may always access the selected item by the [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or `SelectedIndex` properties.

```
private void UserList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedImage = UserList.SelectedItem as StackImage;
    if (selectedImage != null)
    {
        var uri = selectedImage.imageurl;
    }
}
```